# Gurobi does not work any more in Pyomo after getting a new license

Tags: solver, gurobi, pyomo

I have been using Pyomo with a free Academic license for Gurobi and so far it worked quite well. Now my license expired and I received a new license that is stored in the folder

"C:/Gurobi/gurobi.lic"

However, when I now run Pyomo I get the error message:

"ApplicationError: Solver (gurobi) did not exit normally"

and the error is thrown by the last of the following lines:

```
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi')
solver.options['MIPGap'] = 0.1
solver.options['TimeLimit'] = 100
solution = solver.solve(model, tee=True)
```

Do you have any idea why I now get this error? The license itself should be okay according to the Gurobi website (it expires in 2022). I just downloaded it to the before mentioned folder as recommended by Gurobi. Do I have to do anything else?

I'd appreciate every comment.

Update: Here is the full error message:

```
runfile('C:/Users/wi9632/bwSyncShare3/Eigene Arbeit/Code/Python/Demand_Side_Management/Building_1_mHP_EV.py', wdir='C:/Users/wi9632/bwSyncShare3/Eigene Arbeit/Code/Python/Demand_Side_Management')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\wi9632\bwSyncShare3\Eigene Arbeit\Code\Python\Demand_Side_Management\Building_1_mHP_EV.py", line 589, in <module>
    solution = solver.solve(model, tee=True)

  File "C:\Users\wi9632\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 602, in solve
    "Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)

ApplicationError: Solver (gurobi) did not exit normally
```

Comment: Peter - Can you please open a support request with Gurobi? It looks like there is an issue with your license. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all your answers. I just wanted to say that the problem was in fact related to the Gurobi license file. I contacted Gurobi and they could reproduce the error and they just gave me a new license. Now everything is okay again.

Answer (score 3):

This does not look like a license issue. This is a Pyomo error code. You should share some more info about the error message and other output before.
If your new license is stored in `C:\gurobi\gurobi.lic`, Gurobi will find the license automatically and there is usually nothing else required to make it work.

**Update:**
To test the license, it is better to either run `gurobi_cl` from the full Gurobi installation or running this little Python code if only gurobipy is installed:

```
import gurobipy as gp
m = gp.Model()
m.optimize()
```

Comment: Thanks mattmitlen for your comment. I added the full error message in the question. Basically last weak everything worked fine but then I had to renew my license. I just did what is told at the Gurobi website (download the license into the folder `C:\gurobi\gurobi.lic`) via the Windows command prompt. There it was said that there is alreay a license at that path and I decided to overwrite it. Since then, I get this error message on every Pyomo model that I have.

Comment: Any comments to my last comment? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mattmilten. When using your suggested code I get the error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gurobipy'"

Comment: Basically I do not understand why Gurobi does not work anymore in my installation. As said before, one week ago everything was perfect but the license expired. After that I renewed it and did exactly what is told at the Gurobi website (run a command on windows prompt). The strange thing is that I get a message in the windows command prompt that everything was successfull and the new license is stored at a certain location. However, when running a Pyomo model I get the error message `ApplicationError: Solver (gurobi) did not exit normally`

Comment: So the question is what I have to do after activating and creating the new Gurobi license in order to use it with Pyomo? You wrote "Gurobi will find the license automatically and there is usually nothing else required to make it work."But this is just not true for me. The license file is succesfully created and the license is valid (I can see that on the Gurobi page) but I still get that error message that I did not get one week ago before renewing the license. So I guess I have to do something with that license or to store it a certain folder such that Pyomo can find Gurobi as before

Comment: Install the full Gurobi package, please, and then test your license setup with `gurobi_cl` as I mentioned above. There is also a very detailed installation guide on Gurobi's webpage: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/quickstart_windows/retrieving_and_setting_up_.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer mattmilten. I installed the license several times as described on the website but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: When running the windows command prompt as an administrator I can't install the license as I get the following output `C:\WINDOWS\system32>grbgetkey 61e390b2-d587-11eb-8dc0-0242ac130004
info  : grbgetkey version , build v9.1.1rc0
info  : Contacting Gurobi license server...
error : ERROR 405: Cannot reinstall license 656694; get a new license from the Gurobi website

C:\WINDOWS\system32>`

Comment: When running the windows command prompt not as an administrator I can intall the license and I get the following output

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>grbgetkey 61e390b2-d587-11eb-8dc0-0242ac130004
info  : grbgetkey version , build v9.1.1rc0
info  : Contacting Gurobi license server...
info  : License file for license ID 656694 was successfully retrieved
info  : Saving license file...

In which directory would you like to store the Gurobi license file?
[hit Enter to store it in C:\gurobi]:

A license file already exists in 'C:\gurobi\gurobi.lic'
Continue? [Y/n]

info  : License 656694 written to file C:\gurobi\gurobi.lic`

Comment: I tried also to adjust the environment variables according to https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/quickstart_windows/setting_environment_variab.html#subsection:setenvvars  by creating a variable GRB_LICENSE_FILE and setting the path to the license file that is saved in "C:\gurobi\gurobi.lic" (where the installation via the command prompt stored it to). But the problem still exists when running a pyomo model `ApplicationError: Solver (gurobi) did not exit normally`. The model itself is definitely not the problem as I have been running it with another Gurobi license for weeks.

Comment: You did not run `gurobi_cl` to test that license. **The error code is coming from Pyomo - not Gurobi**

Comment: Thanks mattmilten for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it.. I tried to run the `gurobi_cl ` as described in https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/quickstart_windows/testing_your_license.html. For that I openend the Gurobi Interactive Shell. However, shortly after opening it, it closes itself and you can see the message on the window "Warning. Failed to open log file 'gurobi.log'   No HostID specified in license file" and I also tried to start the  Gurobi Token Server. But here the window also closes automatically "Problem with Gurobi license. Unable to star Token Server"

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the new licence in your terminal and run it

**Installation**
To install this license on a computer where Gurobi Optimizer is installed, copy and paste the following command to the Start/Run menu (Windows only) or a command/terminal prompt (any system like mac):

Let's assume your licence is as follows

```
grbgetkey 58eab684-cd60-12eb-b669-0242ac120002
```

The grbgetkey command requires an active internet connection.

Comment: Thanks Optimization team for your answer. What do you mean by terminal and how can I put the licence file there and run it?

Comment: I guess PeterBe is using Windows instead of Linux because he mentioned `C:/Gurobi/gurobi.lic`. Erh. Linux is usually better than windows in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks Optimization team for your answer. Basically I had already done what you suggested before posting my question. I just did it again. The problem still exists. Basically last weak everything worked fine but then I had to renew my license. I just did what is told at the Gurobi website but now I get this error message.

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\System32>grbgetkey 61e390b2-d587-11eb-8dc0-0242ac130004
info  : grbgetkey version , build v9.1.1rc0
info  : Contacting Gurobi license server...
info  : License file for license ID 656694 was successfully retrieved
info  : License expires at the end of the day on 2022-06-20
info  : Saving license file...

In which directory would you like to store the Gurobi license file?
[hit Enter to store it in C:\Users\wi9632]:
A license file already exists in 'C:\Users\wi9632\gurobi.lic'
Continue? [Y/n]

info  : License 656694 written to file C:\Users\wi9632\gurobi.lic`

Comment: Here is the output of the command prompt in Windows. Basically it just tells that everything was okay and a new license is saved. I can also find the license file. What else do I have to do in order to activate the license?

Comment: So the question is what I have to do after activating and creating the new Gurobi license in order to use it with Pyomo? The license file is succesfully created and the license is valid (I can see that on the Gurobi page) but I still get that error message (`ApplicationError: Solver (gurobi) did not exit normally`)that I did not get one week ago before renewing the license. So I guess I have to do something with that license or to store it a certain folder such that Pyomo can find Gurobi as before. Do you have any idea what else I have to do?